# when rbind-ing a data.frame with itself does not create exact duplicates

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this dataframe structure

Data1:

```
  SNP   logp    Allele
rs2929  rs333003    4.46411719154375    T
rs3491  rs405831    4.46411719154375    G
rs1224  rs179639    4.44797917307381    A
```

and Data2 imagine it to be the same (just for testing Data1 too)

when i do :

```
f1=read.table(data1, header=TRUE ,as.is=TRUE)
f3=rbind(f1,f1)
```

i get this result??:

```
  SNP   logp    Allele
rs2929  rs333003    4.46411719154375    T
rs3491  rs405831    4.46411719154375    G
rs1224  rs179639    4.44797917307381    A
rs29291 rs333003    4.46411719154375    T
rs34911 rs405831    4.46411719154375    G
rs12241 rs179639    4.44797917307381    A
```

the problem as you can see is that rs2929 should be copied twice, but instead it will be rs29291  notice all the duplicates are +"1" in the string? thats wrong!? How can i put the to be:

```
  SNP   logp    Allele
rs2929  rs333003    4.46411719154375    T
rs3491  rs405831    4.46411719154375    G
rs1224  rs179639    4.44797917307381    A
rs2929  rs333003    4.46411719154375    T
rs3491  rs405831    4.46411719154375    G
rs1224  rs179639    4.44797917307381    A
```

because thats the real "merge" i want to join 2 files.
I know this might sound weird, because im duplicating values, but thats what i want if that happens.

Comment: ... not that `merge` will help you solve your problem, but instead help you realize you are misusing the verb as it has a total different meaning in R.

Comment: @Miguel, I had to roll back the edits you made to the question and my answer. Everyone's answer was based on the fact that your header had one fewer field names than the number of columns in the file. Without it, everyone's answer will make asolutly no sense. Please leave everything as-is, it's fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `?read.table`:

> row.names   [...]

```
      If there is a header and the first row contains one fewer
      field than the number of columns, the first column in the
      input is used for the row names.  Otherwise if ‘row.names’ is
      missing, the rows are numbered.
```

So in your case the first column is used as rownames, and since R requires that rownames always be unique, it is appending those `1` when you are trying to create duplicates.

One solution would be for you to add a column name in the top left cell of your file or call read.table with `row.names = NULL`:

```
f1 <- read.table(textConnection("

             SNP                logp    Allele
rs2929  rs333003    4.46411719154375         T
rs3491  rs405831    4.46411719154375         G
rs1224  rs179639    4.44797917307381         A   

"), header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE, row.names = NULL)

rbind(f1, f1)
#   row.names      SNP     logp Allele
# 1    rs2929 rs333003 4.464117      T
# 2    rs3491 rs405831 4.464117      G
# 3    rs1224 rs179639 4.447979      A
# 4    rs2929 rs333003 4.464117      T
# 5    rs3491 rs405831 4.464117      G
# 6    rs1224 rs179639 4.447979      A
```

Comment: but how do i delete then the first column with the ID's? because then i want to export this as a new file... and the format to be exactly like the data1 structure.

Comment: Also, why does it needs to be unique? because the data i shown is just a part of it, but actually the file itself, has repetions on the rs2929  and even then the dataframe is able to read it, and use it?
So, i dont understand this is could be a very simple operation, afterall, i just want to combine file a with file b, in the same format, its just appen the rows.

Comment: If your first column has non unique values, you can't use it as row.names of your data.frame, so just treat it as any other column. To do that, and if you want to use `read.table`, you'll NEED TO have a header in that column, i.e., you need to write something in the top left corner of your file.

Comment: If you are not flexible on the file format and you need to keep that top left cell blank, I don't see a way you can use `read.table`. Instead, you'll have to write your own I/O functions using `scan` for example, and it is going to be a little painful.

Comment: Assuming, you have put a name in the top left cell of your file, the code would look like: `f1 <- read.table(myfile, as.is = TRUE)` then possibly `write.table(rbind(f1, f1,), myotherfile, quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)`.

Comment: OH thats exaclty right! The this i missed was:row.names = FALSE

Answer (score 0):

Your leftmost strings ("rs2929", etc) are rownames.  R wants names within an object to be unambiguous, for good reasons, so it is reassigning some names.  The easiest solution is probably to not store this information in a rowname but in a normal column.

```
f1$rs <- rownames(f1)
rownames(f1) <- NULL
f1new <- rbind(f1,f1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your lack of a column label on the first column means they're interpreted as row-labels, not data.

See this:

```
 f1 <- structure(list(X = c("rs2929", "rs3491", "rs1224"), SNP = c("rs333003", 
   "rs405831", "rs179639"), logp = c(4.46411719154375, 4.46411719154375, 
   4.44797917307381), Allele = c("T", "G", "A")), .Names = c("X", 
   "SNP", "logp", "Allele"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

 rbind(f1,f1)
```

R likes unique row-labels.

Comment: Lack of column label? but i have all the headers label!?

Comment: Check right at the start of your post. Your "Data1" has 4 columns and 3 sets of column names.

Answer (score 0):

So i come up with this function that i needed:

```
merge_gwas("final.txt","file1.txt","file2.txt")

merge_gwas<-function (out,a1,a2){
f1=read.table(a1,header=T,as.is=TRUE)
f2=read.table(a2,header=T,as.is=TRUE)
f3<- rbind(f1,f2)
write.table(f3, out,quote = FALSE, sep="\t", row.names = FALSE)
}
```

Thanks everyone